# str_replace() only working with single quotes

Tags: php, str-replace

I was having troubles with a simple thing, and after a long time trying to find out the problem I realize that str_replace does not work with simple quotes. This is my code:

```
<?php
$replaceNL1=str_replace("\n", "NEWLINE", $_POST['txt']);
echo $replaceNL1;
$replaceNL2=str_replace('\n', 'NEWLINE', $_POST['txt']);
echo '<hr>' . $replaceNL2;
?>
```

Only `$replaceNL2` makes the replacement. On the first variable it acts like if there weren't any `str_replace()`. This has never happened to me.

I am using UTF-8 charset.

Comment: I believe you will need two backslashes there, one to escape the backslash.

Comment: @WebnetMobile.com I already did. The original problem has nothing to do with this piece of code. This FC is just the final "problem" I could not simplify, as I usually do before asking. Thx!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Single and double quotes are a different thing in PHP.

[PHP Strings](http://pl.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php):

> Single quoted
>
> The simplest way to specify a string is to enclose it in single quotes
>   (the character ').
>
> To specify a literal single quote, escape it with a backslash (). To
>   specify a literal backslash, double it (\). **All other instances of
>   backslash will be treated as a literal backslash: this means that the
>   other escape sequences you might be used to, such as \r or \n, will be
>   output literally as specified rather than having any special meaning**.

So `"\n"` is newline character, whereas `'\n'` are two character (literaly `\n`) without special meaning.

Comment: Thanks. But why isn't it the same when doing:        `preg_replace("/(\n{2,})/","NWPHAR",$_POST['txt']);` -> It does not replace what I am searching for either.

Comment: I think that you got your regex wrong. This works for me: [snippet](http://codepad.org/vf2nVp8i). Key point here is that `"\n"` is one char but `'\n'` are two characters.

Comment: Why the accepted answer (which works for me) in this StackOverFlow question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1577535/php-regex-to-limit-new-lines-to-a-maxmium-of-two uses single quotes for the same purpose? Anyway yours was the best answer, accepted one. Thanks!

Comment: I think that regex are evaluated in a different way than usual strings (which are in your question). Basicaly you want to tell (by regex) that you want to find newline character, which seems to be working both with single and double quotes, check [this](http://codepad.org/snE2dM6n). Keep in mind that there is no printing involved, just regular expression to look for.

Comment: Why I was downvoted? My answer seems to explain Kenedy` issue.

Answer (score 3):

```
"\n" - String that contains newline character
'\n' - String that contains two characters, a backslash \ and the letter n
```

So you just discovered the differences between single quotes and double quotes in php.